# How do I extract the mobile number of a user registering for my mobile application?

Tags: javascript, cordova, mobile

I am trying to design a login process to be as efficient as possible whereby ideally the user will not require to enter the mobile number into the app, but rather have the app extract the mobile number from the phone itself and auto-fill it into the user details.

It seems that there is a lot of uncertainty on how to achieve this, and I am not asking for a specific solution for either Android or iOS as I am using Cordova (allowing one to use JavaScript to develop cross-platform applications).

Comment: It has be vendor specific solution and you will need plugin to achieve this for sure...

Comment: you seen this : http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/how-to-get-devices-phone-number-using.html

Comment: Refer this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-sim

Comment: Excellent, these should definitely be of aid. Thank you!

Comment: There is no way of doing this, the plugin linked here will fail in most cases, so in the end you'll have to ask the user for the number